# iterm vs. zsh features

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, iterm

I'm confused on why I would need both iterm and zsh because from my understanding both just gives you coloring themes and shortcuts like `gco` instead of `git checkout` or is iterm more known for the former and zsh for the latter?

Comment: You can run a shell other than `zsh` in iTerm. You can run `zsh` in a terminal emulator other than iTerm.  They are two completely different things.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are comparing apples to oranges.

`iTerm` is an application that shows a terminal window. Inside that window a shell will be run. There are many different shells. One of those shells is `zsh`

When it comes to coloring, `iTerm` allows coloring in the shell. The shell itself must also allow coloring, most do by default these days. The shell could be configured to do coloring e.g. when running built in commands like `ls` (configured by the `CLICOLOR` and `LSCOLORS` variable).

By "shortcuts" I think you mean "aliases". Shells allow aliases to be set up. None are normally set up by default, but if you use some standard library for `zsh` like [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) you will get many defaults.

Comment: so what is the reason I need iterm if zsh can have coloring already?

Comment: @stackjlei my answer is a reply to your comment.

Comment: @stackjlei you need iterm (or similar) so you can *run* zsh (or similar).

Answer (score 3):

Iterm does not give you shortcuts like `gco`. It is a terminal emulator. It is the shell ( like `zsh` or `bash` ) that enables you to define `alias`es. All popular shells nowadays provide support for such aliases. But `zsh` along with `oh-my-zsh` do provide a lot of nifty features for git out of the box with just a few lines of extra configuration.

Adding to @Klas's answer:

If your terminal application doesn't support coloring, any colors supported by your shell( zsh or bash or csh ) wouldn't show up. That being said, all basic terminal applications nowadays support basic coloring. So if it is just color support you are looking for, you don't need `Iterm` ( assuming you are using the default `Terminal.app` ).

But there are a lot of really good [features](https://www.iterm2.com/features.html/) of `Iterm` which you might use later down the line. My favourite feature provided by `Iterm` is `Shell integration` and `tmux` support.

Comment: `iTerm` is not a shell; it's a terminal emulator that provides the environment in which `zsh` (or any shell) can run.

Comment: I never intended to say Iterm is a shell. I think my wording could be misunderstoood. will edit it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see how I was confused now.